# Updating generated file

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, file

With this algorithm I update an automatically generated verilog-file. The update within this file is done by commenting the assigned wires to specific ports of module instances.

Is there a better, more elegant or more optimized way to do this than with this algorithm?

```
file_name = "test.v"    # name of the verilog file
test = ".test"          # port name 1
tezt = ".tezt"          # port name 2
dummy = []              # buffer for the updated string

with open(file_name, "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()                                 # clear the file
    for line in lines:
        if test in line or tezt in line:         # check if one of the ports is in the line
            if line[line.index('(')+1] != '/':   # check if the assigned wire is already is commented
                 for c in line:                  # update the line and comment the wire name within the brackets
                    if c == ')':
                        dummy.append("*/")
                    dummy.append(c)
                    if c == '(':
                        dummy.append("/*")
                 line = line.replace(line, "".join(dummy))    # replace the old line with the new string
                 dummy.clear()
        f.write(line)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! "... done by *commenting* the assigned wires ..." should likely be " ... *connecting* ...", no?

Comment: @AlexV Looking at the `dummy.append("*/")`, it looks like the are _commenting_ the wires.

Comment: @Peilonrayz On the second look that might actually be true :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You don't need to manually call `f.close()`, that's what the `with` is for.
- It looks like `line = line.replace(line, "".join(dummy))` can just be `line = "".join(dummy)`.
- It's clearer to define `dummy` in the if statement:

  - This means that it's in the correct scope, meaning we don't have to look out for it being used elsewhere.
  - It also means that you can remove `dummy.clear()`.
- Personally I would merge your two `if` statements together, to reduce the arrow anti-pattern.
- It looks like `dummy` and your `for` loop can be replaced with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

<sub>untested</sub>

```
file_name = "test.v"
test = ".test"
tezt = ".tezt"
trans_table = str.maketrans({'(': '(/*', ')': '*/)'})

with open(file_name, "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        if ((test in line or tezt in line)
            and line[line.index('(') + 1] != '/'
        ):
            line = line.translate(trans_table)
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your improvements. I knew that it could be optimized. The two string methods are new to me, but it's good to know that they exist.